# Where is phpdoc's default.ini located?

Tags: php, pear, phpdoc

I am installing phpdocumentor on Centos/Apache.  I ran the following, and all seemed to work:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
pear install phpdoc/phpdocumentor
pear config-set data_dir /var/www/html/pear
```

When going to http://mydomain.com/pear/phpDocumentor/, I see the following, but nothing I can run in a browser.

```
Index of /pear/phpDocumentor
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -    
[ ] CHANGELOG.md    27-Apr-2014 10:30   17K  
[TXT]   CONTRIBUTING.md 27-Apr-2014 10:30   3.9K     
[ ] Vagrantfile 27-Apr-2014 10:30   643      
[ ] box.json    27-Apr-2014 10:30   4.6K     
[ ] box.phar    27-Apr-2014 10:30   877K     
[ ] composer.json   27-Apr-2014 10:30   2.7K     
[TXT]   composer.lock   27-Apr-2014 10:30   119K     
[DIR]   features/   27-Apr-2014 10:30   -    
[ ] phpmd.xml.dist  27-Apr-2014 10:30   639      
[DIR]   vendor/ 27-Apr-2014 10:30   -
```

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.config-files describes the following:

> There are two configuration files included in the distribution of
>   phpDocumentor, and both are in the user/ subdirectory. ... The best
>   way to ensure your config file matches the format expected by
>   phpDocumentor is to copy the default.ini config file, and modify it to
>   match your needs. Lines that begin with a semi-colon (;) are ignored,
>   and can be used for comments.

I've searched by server using `find / -name default.ini`, and there is not a file of this name.

Where should phpdoc's default.ini be located?

Comment: `data_dir` is a system wide directory that PEAR apps can use to store their internal data. It isn't intended for end user output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up phdoc2 and the phpdocumentor 1 manual.

phpdoc2's manual is at http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html

Comment: I think you are right!  Wow, didn't expect that.  How did you know there were two manuals?

Comment: Because I know phpdoc since 10 years :)